# Don't show detail of product in angular4

Tags: angular, angular-services

When I click on item I need

```
 `<a
  href="#"
  class="list-group-item clearfix"
  (click)="onSelected()">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recipe.name}}</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{recipe.description}}</p>
  </div>
  <span class="pull-right">
        <img
          [src]="recipe.imagepath"
          alt="{{recipe.name}}"
          class="img-responsive"
          style="max-height: 50px;">
      </span>
</a>`
```

item.ts :

```
    import { Component, OnInit,Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Recipe} from '../recipe';
import{RecipeServiceService} from'../../service/recipe-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-item',
  templateUrl: './recipe-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-item.component.css']
})
export class RecipeItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() recipe:Recipe;

  constructor(private recipeservice:RecipeServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onSelected(){
    this.recipeservice.recipeSelected.emit(this.recipe);
    console.log("Item Select",this.recipe);
  }

}
```

Put the selected value in `recipeSelected`

service.ts

```
import{Recipe} from'./../recipe-list/recipe';
import{EventEmitter} from'@angular/core';

export class RecipeServiceService {

  recipeSelected=new EventEmitter<Recipe>();

 private recipes:Recipe[]=[
    new Recipe('انگولار 4', 'بهترین کتاب موجود ', 'http://startupsac.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/AngularJS-Logo.jpg'),
    new Recipe('آموزش Asp Core 1.1 برای مبتدیان', 'آپدیت جدید کتاب', 'https://codeopinion.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/aspnetcore.png')
    ];

  getAllRecipe(){
   return this.recipes.slice();
  }

}
```

And in recipe component, put the value of `recipeSelected` in `selectedRecipe`

recipe.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{RecipeServiceService} from'./service/recipe-service.service';
import{Recipe} from'./recipe-list/recipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipes',
  templateUrl: './recipes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipes.component.css'],
  providers:[RecipeServiceService]
})
export class RecipesComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedRecipe:Recipe;
  constructor(private recipeservice:RecipeServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recipeservice.recipeSelected.subscribe(
      (rec:Recipe)=>{
        this.selectedRecipe=rec;
      })
      console.log("Component Select",this.selectedRecipe);
  }


}
```

html

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
    <app-recipe-list></app-recipe-list>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
   <app-recipe-detail *ngIf="selectedRecipe; else infoText"
   [recipe]="selectedRecipe"></app-recipe-detail>
  <ng-template #infoText>
    Please Select Recipe
    </ng-template>
  </div>

</div>
```

It shows me the list but when I click the item it doesn't show me the details of the recipe. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a copy of https://github.com/crispinandrade/RecipeBookApp/ code. Try to run it first and compare you copy with it. There is no problem here.

Comment: i checked every things , and copy the cod but it not work . whats the problem ?

Comment: to run the mentioned link's project, 1st install `Angular CLI` and then run `npm install` and `ng serve -o`. It just works and it's the same as your code.